# Is it worth switching to Ubuntu if I already have VirtualBox + Mintty on my Windows?

Tags: windows

I am using Docker + VirtualBox for Linux applications and Git, Bash, and Mintty for interacting with file systems on my Windows 7.

Is it worth switching my whole system to Ubuntu? What does Ubuntu have to offer over these tools I'm currently using on my Windows?

Comment: Well, it depends on your needs, maibe you can eloborate and explain what use of these tools you have and what you want to do with Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does Ubuntu have to offer over these tools I'm currently using on my windows?

Ubuntu has a better security track record than Windows.

Let's say your Windows got hit by a cryptolocker (those tend to ignore anything outside `/home` since it requires sudo access and with some basic alterations to the default setup it is easy to protect your own content in `/home`). That will lock down your whole system including your containers that hold Ubuntu. Good luck getting your system up and running again.

If you have Ubuntu with Windows in Virtualbox, only the content of your Virtualbox instance would be locked. Restore the backup of your Windows container and your loss should be a minimum of data.

Comment: Hehe. Already installed Ubuntu and wine for my games :)

Comment: And I just discovered my Ubuntu takes only 2 seconds to poweroff. Have never seen anything like it in Windows :/

Comment: @MD.MohiuddinAhmed: there will be many more so far unseen miracles you will encounter :)

Comment: @MD.MohiuddinAhmed that depends on services that you use. I have mysql and apache. It takes a bit longer to shutdown than 2 seconds when those are active.

Comment: Yup. It looks like my past fresh windows installations could not make it that fast :D